# Is there any way to use NLog or log4net in a Xamarin.Mac Project?

Tags: xamarin, log4net, nlog, xamarin.mac

When I try to add NLog or log4net NuGet packages to my Xamarin.Mac project, it fails with:

> Could not install package 'NLog 3.2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Are there any ports of these tools to work with Xamarin.Mac? If not, are there any equivalent tools that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

We've an app that works on both Mac and Windows.
We downloaded the source [from the log4net github page](https://github.com/apache/log4net/) and re-build on Mac. Works fine and the resulting binary can be dropped into Windows apps..

Answer (score 0):

log4net works fine with Xamarin.Mac, just reference the log4net.dll in the Xamarin.Mac project, and use 'log4net' namespace in your code.